# Parent height is changing according to it's visible children height with CSS only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have such structure:

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dialog">
      <div class="content-0"></div>
      <div class="content-1"></div>
      <div class="content-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent element .dialog holds three content items which are horizontally aligned. Visible is only active .content-*. Other content items are hidden. When user clicks button, active item is sliding to the left to the hidden area, and next item becomes active and visible
Here is fiddle to demonstrate the behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/fmbn28xs/

My question here - how can I adjust parent (.dialog) height every time user clicks button according to visible content (.content-*) item height only with CSS, is that possible?

Update:
Height of content items is not known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with custom css properties(preview with full page):

```js
var index = 0;
function slide() {
  index++;
  var current = index % 3;
  var target = document.querySelector(`.dialog`);
  target.style.setProperty('--index', current);
}
```

```css
.body {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 20%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dialog {
  --index: 0;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(200px + 50px * var(--index));
  transition: transform 400ms, height 400ms;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--index) * -100%));
}
.content-0, .content-1, .content-2 {
  width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content-0 {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: calc(200px + 50px * 0);
}

.content-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: calc(200px + 50px * 1);
}

.content-2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: calc(200px + 50px * 2);
}

button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dialog">
      <div class="content-0"></div>
      <div class="content-1"></div>
      <div class="content-2"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="slide()">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But you have to assign the height for all the content manually.

If you're using a precompile css library(such as scss), you can also automate this:

```
.dialog > *{
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      height: calc(200px + 50px * #{$i});
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Update

If the height is dynamic, you can use tricks with `animation` associate with alternating `position` from `relative` to `absolute` to make the container height
adapts accordingly, but this way you can't animate the height change, since the height is determined by the height of its children.

```js
var index = 0;
function slide() {
  index++;
  var current = index % 3;
  var target = document.querySelector(`.dialog`);
  target.style.setProperty('--index', current);
  target.setAttribute('data-index', current);
}
```

```css
.body {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 20%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dialog {
  --index: 0;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.dialog > * {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: popout 400ms both;
  top: 0;
}

.dialog[data-index='0'] > *:nth-child(1), 
.dialog[data-index='1'] > *:nth-child(2), 
.dialog[data-index='2'] > *:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: popin 400ms both;
}

.content-0 {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 200px;
}

.content-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 250px;
}

.content-2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes popin {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes popout {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dialog" data-index="0">
      <div class="content-0"></div>
      <div class="content-1"></div>
      <div class="content-2"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="slide()">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, solution, thanks for your help. Unfortunately in my case it's not applicable, as I do not know the height of the content items in advance, so the height of children may be quite diverse

Comment: @IevgenChernetsov I've added another solution, see if that helps

Comment: this is perfect, height animation is not so critical. Appreciate your help, I struggled a lot, and your solution solve the goal